# how to get for each instance in the test data the probability for each class in libsvm in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am using package e1071 for libsvm in R. But I don't know how to get  for each instance in the test dataset, the probability of it belonging to each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what `probability` flag is for

```
library(e1071)

model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris, probability=TRUE)
preds <- predict(model, iris, probability=TRUE)

head(attr(preds, "probabilities"))

#      setosa versicolor   virginica
# 1 0.9803339 0.01129740 0.008368729
# 2 0.9729193 0.01807053 0.009010195
# 3 0.9790435 0.01192820 0.009028276
# 4 0.9750030 0.01531171 0.009685342
# 5 0.9795183 0.01164689 0.008834838
# 6 0.9740730 0.01679643 0.009130620
```